# WxPython Size Reduction

Tags: python, wxpython

In have built wxpython phoenix on Linux CentOS 7 but the size of the complete module is around 250 MB and we don't need all the widgets.

Is there anyway to reduce the size of Wxpython?

Comment: If you need some help, please, provide the details for your configuration and then, it will be possible to provide you a more accurate answer :).

Comment: I build it using the default configuration.Just followed the standard steps.